# Limit the growth of a VirtualBox mass storage

Tags: virtualbox

I have a VirtualBox running Debian 8.6 Jessie; the `/var` tree is on a `.vdi` file of its own.

Now I have trouble because of the growth of that mass storage image file. According to `df -h`, the `/dev/sdb1` device mounted to `/var` contains 97G of data, but the container file is almost twice the size (189.249.163.264 B). There should be enough space in the container, but it grows nevertheless.  This is a problem, because the size of the Windows partition is limited where it lives, and during the last days the VBox happened to stop a few times because of this.

I modified the `/etc/fstab` line, appending `0 2`, to have it `fsck`-ed after reboot:

```
UUID=abc12345-6789-ab12-a3ad-97a2ae2f5a8d /var ext3 auto 0 2
```

Will the image file keep growing until the maximum "virtual size" is reached?

Can I reduce that maximum size without cloning the image?

With the VBox cleanly shut down, I tried:

```
VBoxManage.exe modifymedium disk d:\path\to\disk-var.vdi --compact --resize 125829120
```

… but the progress indicator keeps showing `0%...`.

**Edit**: After about ten minutes, there *was* a change: The progress indicator changed to `0%...10%...`. Meanwhile I read about `--resize` beeing able to *increase* only (not in the help written to `stderr` by `VBoxManage.exe` v5.1.8) and wondered whether it would be safe to `Ctrl+Break`, and why the program didn't reject an unsupported value ...

**Edit 2**: The operation has failed meanwhile, obviously because of lack of disk space:

```
%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%
0%...
Progress state: VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR
VBoxManage.exe: error: Failed to resize medium
VBoxManage.exe: error: Could not resize medium 'd:\path\to\disk-var.vdi' (VERR_DISK_FULL)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80bb0004), component MediumWrap, interface IMedium
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "enum RTEXITCODE __cdecl handleModifyMedium(struct HandlerArg *)" at line 711 of file VBoxManageDisk.cpp
```

I'm currently trying again with `--compact` only, since perhaps the `--compact` operation might have succeeded without the `--resize` ...

**Edit 3**: Indeed the operation completed without an error, but the size of the physical file has not changed.

Comment: Compact is not for changing the disk's maximum size. Compact is to reduce the disk's size right now. When you delete data on a dynamically allocated disk, the vdi file doesn't shrink. The now empty space in the vdi just stays empty. The disk dynamically expands, but does not dynamically shrink. Compact is the shrink.

Comment: If it's taking that long, a hunch tells me that it is indeed just copying the disk to a new file. Once copied, it'll assign the new file the same UUID as the original file, and then delete the original. If so, you can do that yourself :)

Comment: Yes, that's what I expected the `--compact` command to do: free the space to make the size of the `.vdi` file more or less match the used space as reported by `df -h`. This would have helped me a lot; sadly it didn't work: the `.vdi` file didn't shrink by a single byte.